# Check value of preprocessor argument during compile time

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have an macro that checks mulitiple options during compiletime through the concatination operator, like this:

```
#define macro_bigger printf("is bigger")
#define macro_smaller(x) macro_##x
```

How can i check on compiletime if the argument is set to neither of these values?

Comment: Neither of what values?

Comment: You mean they didn't write `macro_smaller(bigger)` or `macro_smaller(smaller)`?

Comment: yes, what if the argument given isnt "bigger" or "smaller"?

Comment: There will be an error because there's no function `macro_othervalue()`

Comment: What happens if you simply try?